# CSS display block doesn't work on a certain element

Tags: jquery, html, css

In the sliding menu I created, I set up two close buttons (close-btn-2 and close-btn) for each one perform a different slide animation, triggered by jQuery (close-btn = slide right to left/ close-btn-2 = slide top to bottom) when screen change size.

When screen size shrinks, close-btn_2 is shown dynamically through jQuery (through the show method) whereas close-btn is hidden in the same way.

The only issue that I am facing is that, when I hover over close-btn-2, the  element changes color just around the "X" tag and not the entire block. Whereas the other close btn works just fine, as the other menu elements are.

What is wrong with the styling?

HTML:

```
<div class="sidebar">
        <a href="#" id="close-btn">&times;</a>
        <a href="#" id="close-btn-2">&times;</a>
        <a href="#">Accomodations</a>
        <a href="#">Services</a>
        <a href="#">Merchandising</a>
        <a href="#">About us</a>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.sidebar {
   height: 640px;
   width: 0px;
   background-color: black;
   float: right;
   overflow: hidden;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   transition: 0.5s;
   -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
   -moz-transition: 0.5s;
 }

.sidebar a {
   display: block;
   text-decoration: none;
   padding: 20px;
   font-size: 20px;
}

.sidebar a:hover {
   background-color: #ff0066;
   color: black;
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

Jquery

```
else if (width < 415) {

      $("#menu-btn").hide();
      $("#menu-btn-2").show();

      $("#close-btn").hide();
      $("#close-btn-2").show();

      $("#menu-btn-2").on("click", function() {
         $(".sidebar").attr("id", "topbar-on");
         $(".inner-title").fadeOut("fast"); 
      });

      $("#close-btn-2").on("click", function() {
         $(".sidebar").removeAttr("id", "topbar-on");
         $(".inner-title").fadeIn("slow");  
      });


  }
```

[image: close button style]

[image: Other elements style]

Comment: Why don't you use css media queries?

Comment: @denis I tried to add the display attribute through media query but it doesn't work either

Comment: have you checked that - is close-btn-2 set to display:none after its dynamically added to html? sometimes in dynamically addition, element added later but events or code runs first ( According to your script sequence)

Comment: I just edited the question because I made a mistake. What I'am asking for is the display:block property

Comment: Also i would say that on the console (google chrome) the close-btn-2 menu is always displayed with the display:inline attribute, no matter what I set as display property for this element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, I messed it up a little.

First of all, I decided to use a single close button (which by the way I switched to a button tag). I gave it a width and a height (in addition to the display:block css property) so to make it use the entire width of the menu and have the hover animation work the way I was looking for.

As @denis suggested, media query where much more easier to use for responsiveness, so I took rid of the all jQuery window.resize situation and used media queries to change style of the styling menu.